# In Matthew 5:44, what is meant by "enemies"?

Tags: matthew

In Matthew 5:44 where it says "love your enemies" what is covered here? I mean can enemies be muslims or atheists? Is there any restriction to the meaning of "enemies"?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Can people please answer in an answer, rather than answer in comments?

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, there is no restriction.

However, I don't believe this implies that we need to literally have a 'list' of enemies, and *then* love them. I believe it's God telling us that everyone requires love, understanding. If you show love, you can't have an enemy.

Once again, we as human beings fall short, thus require Jesus.

Comment: In support of this good answer, remember the parable of the Good Samaritan.  A lawyer asks Jesus "who is my neighbor?"  After the parable, Jesus turned the question around, "who was neighbor unto him?"  We're expected to be everyone's neighbor, we're expected to love (have charity toward, seek the best welfare of) everyone.  Even people who today we don't like politically.  Perhaps especially those we don't like politically.